# How to get depth of web elements with static position?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, position, z-index

Building a web crawler, I tried to access the z-indices of all web elements after successfully locating them.  But the z-indices are all "auto" since they are all with property "position":"static" in both chrome and firefox in my win10.
In comparison, Debanjan answered that he successfully got the integer values of z-indices of those elements in his experiment for the same page with chrome.
Does this mean some settings of the webdriver or browsers affect the default position property ?
Can I change the elements' position property at runtime to get their z-indices without affecting the rendering of the page layout ?
If yes, how should I do it ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To get actual z-index you can use `getComputedStyle` Javascript as below:

```
element = driver.find_element()
zindex = driver.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).zIndex", element)
```

And to update:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.zIndex = 999", element)
```

Details you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility).

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the
>   values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active
>   stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
>   contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs
>   provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

[image]

Comment: Hi, dear Sers:  Thanks for the solution.  I will try tomorrow and get back to you quickly.